# top and bottom padding for background-position

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks, on the middle block there is a line that I added with the `background` property

Now this line is only indented at the top

The question is whether it is possible to make the same indentation from below?

I looked at all the properties for `background-position` but there seems to be no way to indent both top and bottom

```css
* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.block1 {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) center bottom / 2px calc(100% - 60px) no-repeat;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just remove "bottom" from the background property value.

```css
* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.block1 {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) center / 2px calc(100% - 60px) no-repeat;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```